# getting every div id in child page in iFrame DOM, then generate UL list from those ids in Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have parent document and iframe child as listed below:

**parent.html**

```
<div id="parent">
    <iframe src="child.html"></iframe>
</div>
<div><!-- the UL List getting from child.html will be displayed here--></div>
```

**child.html**

```
<div id="child_element_1"></div>
<div id="child_element_2">
    <div id="child_element_2_1"></div>
    <div id="child_element_2_2"></div>
</div>
<div id="child_element_3">
    <div id="child_element_3_1"></div>
</div>
```

What I want to have is, a UL list, which has a hierarchy of every div id in child.html. (see the picture below)

[image]

After that, I want to put the UL somewhere in parent.html
I really appreciate your support in advance. Both Jquery or JavaScript are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following assumes iFrame is on same domain, otherwise you have no script access.

```
/* page load code*/
$(function(){
    $('#iframeID').on('load',function(){   
        iframeToList( $(this).contents().find('body'))
    });
});

function divToList( $root){
     var html=['<ul>'];
    $root.children('div[id]').each( function(){
        html.push('<li>'+this.id);
        var $children=$(this).children('div[id]')
        if( $children.length){
            html.push( divToList( $(this)))
        }
         html.push('</li>')
    })
    html.push('</ul>')
    return html.join('');

}

function iframeToList( $root){
    $('body').append( divToList($root));    
}
```

**DEMO:** 
Due to bug in Chrome am unable to trigger `load` without an `src` for dynamically created iframe so have browser dependent demos:

http://jsfiddle.net/efzCu/2  - Works IN firefox

http://jsfiddle.net/efzCu/3  - Works IN Chrome

Live page with a real `src` won't require browser dependent code

Comment: thank you much for your help, but I cannot see anything displayed in the demo link [link](http://jsfiddle.net/efzCu/1)

Comment: what browser? I just shortened code and changed link to demo also...but should work

Comment: Chrome does not display anything. But Firefox could display properly.

Comment: OK..found bug in Chrome, won't trigger `'load` without there being an `src` for iframe...this works in Chrome  http://jsfiddle.net/efzCu/3/. Problem won't exist on your page since you have an `src` but my demo didn't

Comment: it's quite weird. I tested your code on my real system with real src. However, the tree shows only first level div. The rest sub level divs are not displayed. Could you please check this issue?

Comment: do you have other `DIV` with no ID in html? How can I check, my demo works, I have nothing to check against

Comment: You are right, your example works well. The problem is caused by my CSS issue. Thanks again.